# Is there a quicker way to calculate the square of quadratic polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

For example, consider

$$ (x^2 - 6 x + 7)^2  $$

Apart from

$$ x^2 (x^2-6x+7) - 6x (x^2-6x+7)+ 7 (x^2-6x+7) $$

are there any quicker ways of calculation the square of $x^2 - 6 x + 7$?

Comment: is the tag correct? Also, generally, no. For some particular cases you might find easier methods

Comment: Why do you tag the "equation" with an asterisk when you make no later reference to it?

Comment: You can use the multinomial theorem, but in your example it is probably overkill.

Comment: In the case of square of sums, there is a convenient formula : $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_n\right)^2=\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2+2\sum_{k<\ell}a_k a_\ell.$$ But I suppose that's not what you expected, because there isn't any *simple* way for a general formula. So, no.

Comment: Use identity: $(A+B+C)^2=A^2+B^2+C^2+2AB+2BC+2CA$ $$\therefore \color{red}{(ax^2+bx+c)^2}=a^2x^4+b^2x^2+c^2+2abx^3+2bcx+2acx^2$$$$=\color{blue}{a^2x^4+2abx^3+(2ac+b^2)x^2+2bcx+c^2}$$

Comment: $$
(ax^2 + bx +c)^2 = a^2x^4 + 2abx^3 + (b^2 +2ac)x^2 + 2bcx + c^2
$$
$$
(a,b,c) \mapsto (a^2,\,\,\,\, 2ab,\,\,\,\, b^2 + 2ac,\,\,\,\, 2bc,\,\,\,\, c^2)
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for replying, i don't know what tag should i use indeed.

Comment: @user12595983 : You don't need to use any tag. My question was why you include a tag when you don't use it to refer to that line later. Now I've deleted the tag.

Answer (score 1):

In your mind visualise a three column by three row answer grid.

The column headings are $x^2$,$-6x$ and $7$, the row headings the same.
Write down the bits as you visualise the row, column intersections.
On the leading diagonal will be $x^4$, $36x^2$ and $49$

Each of the other answers occurs twice.
So, essentially, you are trying to visualise the following.

$$\begin{bmatrix}x^2 & -6x &7 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}x^2 \\ -6x \\7 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x^4 & -6x^3 &7x^2 \\-6x^3 & 36x^2 & -42x\\7x^2 &-42x &49\end{bmatrix}$$

With practice you should be able to simply write down the "almost answer",
$$x^4+36x^2+49-12x^3+14x^2-84x$$
and it depends on how much you can carry in your head as to if you want to gather together like terms at the same time.
Such mental gymnastics helps to keep the algebra interesting.

The party piece is to do similar with $(x^2-7x+6)^3$ by visualising a cube!

Here is a link to a diagram of the technique as a "visual proof" (on FaceBook) : https://www.facebook.com/examath/photos/a.166108407455452/541471543252468/